# Creating ViewController in landscape orientation on iPhone

Tags: ios, orientation, xib, viewcontroller

In my app, I need to load new view controller at the moment when user click button. I load it from XIB file. And it is appears according to ORIENTATION set in XIB file (in view's "simulated metrics"), not actual device orientation.

How can I change view's orientation problematically?

**Note:**
As soon as View controller loaded it handles orientation change events correct and auto-resize everything correct on rotation.

**EDITED:**
I make it works by adding another XIB file for landscape orientation:

```
[self initWithNibName: ( UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) ? @"tfdSearchViewController_iPhone_Landscape" : @"tfdSearchViewController_iPhone" )]
```

But it is silly, because **the only difference** between 2 xib files is "orientation" value.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

change device  orientation just set it to what u want

Comment: I don't want to change device orientation. I want set orientation in XIB according device orientation. Like `self.view.orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`. But `view.orientation` is not exists.

Comment: view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
i hope this solve ur problem